# Minimal time encryption algorithm for MQTT

Tags: encryption

What is the minimal computation time algorithm that I can use for E2E encryption in MQTT protocol which has never been used before

Comment: Does [this list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/aead-parameters/aead-parameters.xhtml) satisfy you?

Comment: Hi & welcome falcon.  Err, what do you mean by _"never been used before"_?

Comment: Like the novel algorithm which could never been applied to MQTT but existed and which has better performance metrics than AES